# Linux: Find Images greater than 500x500 then move to some folder (Find+Xargs+Mv)

Tags: linux, find, xargs, mv

After running PhotoRec to recover photos after accidentally formatting my data partition, I'm left with 100s of directories with recovered images in them.
Using **Identity** command, I'm able to find all photos of interest (larger than 500x500). 
But when I use **xargs** to push the out to a **mv** command, I get Permission Denied! I'm using **sudo**!

```
sudo find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '{if ($1>300 || $2>300) print $3}' | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' /home/simon/decent_size/
```

Output:

```
mv: cannot move ‘./recup_dir.3042/f848232448.jpg’ to ‘/home/simon/decent_size/f848232448.jpg’: Permission denied
mv: cannot move ‘./recup_dir.3042/f848239136.jpg’ to ‘/home/simon/decent_size/f848239136.jpg’: Permission denied
mv: cannot move ‘./recup_dir.571/f703451808.jpg’ to ‘/home/simon/decent_size/f703451808.jpg’: Permission denied
mv: cannot move ‘./recup_dir.2771/f835113704.jpg’ to ‘/home/simon/decent_size/f835113704.jpg’: Permission denied
...
```

Thank you for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `find` commands runs with root rights but not your `xargs`.

You want something like this:

```
sudo find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '{if ($1>300 || $2>300) print $3}' | sudo xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' /home/simon/decent_size/
```

> I didn't check the logic of your command, just fixed the 'permission denied' problem.

Comment: Thanks heaps mate :) I managed to figure out the second sudo just as I got notified about ur answer :) (mine was a pure guess hehe)